# XML Feed: attribute type array

Tags: php, xml, opencart2.x

I'm building simple XML Feed to display all products stored in store (Opencart)

I've a file "Commerce XML Feed Product Specification" with rules that I must follow when building the XML feed, I have one question about this rule:

[image]

I'm not sure how to add the array attribute. Any idea how to do it?

I'm building the XML feed to be closer to this demo:

http://demo.plusmotiv.com/allsub/index.php?route=feed/xmlfeedbasic

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Nothing so far, I've no idea how to implement it, but I'm thinking to make one parent element for all categories and all subcategories will be children